# Passing variable onto next screen in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

So, I've got a screenmanager `sm` and two screens, `ActivitiesWindow` and `ActivityDoneWindow`. An attribute of `ActivitiesWindow` is `self.current_activity`, a string, which I would like to pass on to the window `ActivityDoneWindow`. For context: First page (ActivitiesWindow) generates a random activity from a csv file based on user input, second page (ActivityDoneWindow) is accessed when the user presses a button stating that he/she will do that activity, where I would ultimately like to show the activity they are doing, creating the need to pass `current_activity` on.

**python file**

```
class ActivitiesWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super().__init__(**kw)
        self.current_activity = None
        self.previous_activity = None
        self.want_exercise = None
        self.want_intensity = range(1, 10)  # Default intensity

    def is_done(self):
    """If user states that he/she has done the activity, this function updates the stats in csv file"""

    # Reading csv and copying to directory
    csv_read = csv.reader(open(filename, newline=''))
    lines = list(csv_read)

    # Changing csv values
    for row in lines:
        if row[1] == self.current_activity:
            # Converting to int to add, then back to string to store updated value in csv
            amount = int(row[4]) + 1
            row[4] = str(amount)
            print(f'Activity {self.current_activity} done. It has now been done {row[4]} times')

    # Changing csv file to locally changed csv
    csv_write = csv.writer(open(filename, 'w', newline=''))
    csv_write.writerows(lines)

    # MAIN PROBLEM IS HERE!
    # Finally, pass on the current activity to new window
    self.manager.screen_names.activity_done.current_activity = self.current_activity

class ActivityDoneWindow(Screen):
    pass
```

**kv file from which program is ran**

```
#:include activities.kv

sm:
    ActivitiesWindow:
    ActivityDoneWindow:
```

**kv file**

```
<ActivitiesWindow>:
    name: "activities"
    
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Let's do it!"
            id: do_activity
            on_release:
                root.manager.transition.direction = "down"
                root.manager.current = "activity_done"
                root.is_done()

<ActivityDoneWindow>:
    name: "activity_done"

    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Back"
            id: back_to_activities
            on_release:
                root.manager.transition.direction = "up"
                root.manager.current = 'activities'

    Label:
        text: "Great! Way to go"

    Label:
        text: f"Have fun with activity '{root.current_activity}'"
```

I've removed some of the irrelevant code to keep it compact. Generating the activity works perfectly, my main problem is how to properly pass on the variable by calling `ActivityDoneWindow`. Any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: Form what I understand you want to show the current_activity in the ActivityDoneWindow screen.

Comment: @FadiAbuRaid Yes, that is true. Either by calling the current_activity attribute of ActivitiesWindow or by making is_done() pass it on so it becomes an attribute of ActivityDoneWindow. I think the latter would be more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

The way Kivy works is the Python script is the backend and .kv file is the frontend. You have to update your frontend using the backend. From my understanding you can't pass a variable to the frontend.

To change the label text first you can give it an id then update it using the id.

**Python file**

```
class ActivitiesWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super().__init__(**kw)
        self.current_activity = None
        self.previous_activity = None
        self.want_exercise = None
        self.want_intensity = range(1, 10)  # Default intensity

    def is_done(self):
        """If user states that he/she has done the activity, this function updates the stats in csv file"""

        # Reading csv and copying to directory
        csv_read = csv.reader(open(filename, newline=''))
        lines = list(csv_read)

        # Changing csv values
        for row in lines:
            if row[1] == self.current_activity:
                # Converting to int to add, then back to string to store updated value in csv
                amount = int(row[4]) + 1
                row[4] = str(amount)
                print(f'Activity {self.current_activity} done. It has now been done {row[4]} times')

        # Changing csv file to locally changed csv
        csv_write = csv.writer(open(filename, 'w', newline=''))
        csv_write.writerows(lines)

        # Get the current app
        app= App.get_running_app()
        # Update the label text using the id
        app.root.ids['message'].text= f"Have fun with activity '{self.current_activity}'"

class ActivityDoneWindow(Screen):
    pass
```

**kv file**

```
<ActivitiesWindow>:
    name: "activities"
    
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Let's do it!"
            id: do_activity
            on_release:
                root.manager.transition.direction = "down"
                root.manager.current = "activity_done"
                root.is_done()

<ActivityDoneWindow>:
    name: "activity_done"

    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Back"
            id: back_to_activities
            on_release:
                root.manager.transition.direction = "up"
                root.manager.current = 'activities'

        Label:
            text: "Great! Way to go"

        Label:
            id:message
            text: ""
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You're saying that you can't pass back-end variables to the front-end but what I intended to do was pass from back-end to back-end (via different Screen classes in Python) and then to the front-end.

Anyhow, I've changed my script to the edited one you posted but now I get a KeyError with the label id 'message' as faulty key.

Comment: Do you have ```id: message```  in your .kv file under the label as shown in the code above.

Comment: Yes, I do. It's strange, I'd expect it to work as well. I have the exact code you have, apart from some kv attributes such as color and font_size. I can hardly imagine the problem lies there and it makes the code a whole lot easier to read in essence of the problem.

Comment: Check the indentation in the kv file. I have just fixed an issue with the indentation. labels should be inside the FloatLayout.